Как заставить игрока смотреть в ту же самую сторону после проигрывания анимации?
Я делаю top down игру.
После ходьбы вправо или влево, я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы игрок смотрел в то же направление после ходьбы.
То есть, если игрок сходит налево, то и после ходьбы он должен смотреть налево, но не вниз.
Буду благодарен за решение этой проблемы)
Код игрока:
{
    public float speed;
    public Vector2 direction;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Animator animator;
    private bool facingRight = true;
    
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        direction.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        direction.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        
        animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", direction.x);
        animator.SetFloat("Vertical", direction.y);
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", direction.sqrMagnitude);
    
        
    }
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + direction * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        if(facingRight == false && direction.x > 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        if (facingRight == true && direction.x < 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
    
    }  
    
    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 scaler = transform.localScale;
        scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = scaler;
        
}

